# Using non-standard launcher icon sizes in Android

Tags: android, icons

I know what the [standard pixel sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196511/3681880) are for the launcher icon.

```
mdpi
    48 × 48    (legacy)
    108 x 108  (adaptive)

hdpi
    72 × 72    (legacy)
    162 x 162  (adaptive)

xhdpi
    96 × 96    (legacy)
    216 x 216  (adaptive)

xxhdpi
    144 × 144  (legacy)
    324 x 324  (adaptive)

xxxhdpi
    192 × 192  (legacy)
    432 x 432  (adaptive)
```

I made an icon for my app [using the Android Studio Asset Studio to generate those sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46196511/3681880).

However, I noticed another app with a similar icon had a much crisper look on my Android 5.0 device. When I extracted the resources from that app's APK file I saw that the developer used a 300 x 300 pixel image for all the density sizes. I don't like to go against the standards, but it really looks a lot better in this case.

If I use a single higher resolution image (`300 x 300 px` or maybe `512 x 512 px`), are there any negative consequences that could be noticed by a user? (For example, does it slow the app loading time on lower density devices? Does it cause crashes?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) It will lead to a minute slow down of the device because it needs to get the corresponding resource every time when it is run. See [this loop](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

[image]

2) Re-scaling overhead. Your icons may be used not only by your app, but also by a few other things. For example, launchers, setting apps for installed software, and share menus in many places. [*(reference)*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17629254)

3) It doesn't fit perfectly on all screens. It will make some minor dislocations and cause the boundary lines of the image (like the corners, etc.) to not fit.

So the recommendation is to follow the guidelines of Android Applications Development.